# python requests post to url query parameter requires special character

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using python requests to submit a post request to a specific url. This url has a query parameter that contains the actual filepath of the file I am uplaoding, with the actual colon (':') and backslashes('\') (it will not accept %3A, or %5C). I have no idea what to do.

Here is my code:

```
with requests.Session() as s:

 payload_10_vo_params = {
    'hidInputControlValues': this_hidInputControlValues10,
    'hidFormNames': this_hidFormNames10,
    'hidToken': this_hidToken10,
    'hidFileNm': r"C:\fakepath\{}".format(this_FileName),
    'hidFileSourceId': '',
    'ReUploadInd': ''
}

payload10_mpe_vo = MultipartEncoder(
    [
        ('hidLoanTranSaveFlag', 'TRUE'),
        ('hidUpfrontMIPct', ''),
        ('radLeadRequestOptBtnImportRetNum', 'LUPL'),
        ('txtCorrCompId', ''),
        ('cboLeadRequestFileTypCd', 'DU32'),
        ('txtLeadRequestSelectFile', (this_FileName, open(this_FileName, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')),
        ('txaLoanTranComments', ''),
    ], boundary=ct_disp_bndry_10_final_str)

headers10 = {
    "Accept": "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)",
    "UA-CPU": "AMD64",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary={}".format(ct_disp_bndry_10_final_str),
    "Referer": "referer string",
    "Host": "host string"}

resp10 = s.post(url10, headers=headers10, params=payload_10_vo_params,  data=payload10_mpe_vo)
```

Here is the value of the response url from fiddler, please see the final parameter(the value for `hidFileNm`), everything else is matching fine, (those special characters are for the special character §, which was encoded perfectly by requests).

> POST /SRVCorrBP/LeadMgmt/Application/Lead/LeadSubmitNew.jsp?hidInputControlValues=�DU32�Y�LUPL�C%3A%5CFAKEPATH%5CMAYRA%20CORTEZ.FNM�&hidFormNames=�frmLoanTran~TRUE~�&hidToken=1508961847871LSXG_EDTLeadSummary&hidFileNm=C:\fakepath\filename&hidFileSourceId=&ReUploadInd=

This is what I get:

> /SRVCorrBP/LeadMgmt/Application/Lead/LeadSubmitNew.jsp?hidInputControlValues=%C2%A7DU32%C2%A7Y%C2%A7LUPL%C2%A7C%3A%5CFAKEPATH%5CBOPPPMVO.FNM%C2%A7&hidFormNames=%C2%A7frmLoanTran~TRUE~%C2%A7&hidToken=1512952710233LSXG_EDTLeadSummary&hidFileNm=C%3A%5Cfakepath%5Cfilename&hidFileSourceId=&ReUploadInd=

As you can see, the `hidFileNm` parameter is supposed to be

> hidFileNm=hidFileNm=C:\fakepath\filename

But my request is posting as:

> hidFileNm=C%3A%5Cfakepath%5Cfilename

I've used requests many times before but this is the first time I have run into this issue.

Comment: you will have to manually create `url` with all parameters.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** it worked before but it seems they change something and it doesn't work any more.

---

`requests` automatically escapes parameters before it adds them to url.

You have to manually create string with url and all parameters.

create strings `key=value`

```
args = ['{}={}'.format(k, v) for k,v in payload_10_vo_params.items()]
```

create one string `key1=value1&key2=value2`

```
args_in_one_string = "&".join(args)
```

create url with parameters

```
url10 = url10 + "?" + args_in_one_string
```

---

**EDIT:** there is some [prepared-request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) and example in [request issues](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1839)

```
from requests import Request, Session

s = Session()
req = Request('GET', url)
prepped = s.prepare_request(req)
prepped.url = prepped.url.replace('.', '%2E')
resp = s.send(prepped)
```

but I don't know if it can help.

Maybe you will have to use `urllib`

Comment: Thank you! I will work on this tomorrow and let you know what I find.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
payload_10_vo_params = urlencode(payload_10_vo_params, doseq=True, quote_via=lambda x,y,z,w: x)
```

before calling `s.post`. 
Internally `requests` use `urlencode` to get the string for `params` and by default `urlencode` will call `quote_plus()` to escape the parameters. Using the option `quote_via` can change the function called for quoting the url. In this case, a dummy quote function which just return its first argument is used.

Comment: Thanks @Roun ! I will try this tomorrow and let you know what I find.

Comment: Hey Roun, I updated my code with your instructions and it seems to work for everything except for the '\'. It might just be the way the request module handles the backslash character. I'll see what happens if i do the whole thing without using the requests module. I'll probably use your code for other things though, thank you!